# Arithmetic with IPv6 addresses (large integers)

Tags: delphi, network-programming, math, int128

I'm working with IPv6 addresses in the form:

FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF

Internally, I store them in an array:

```
TIp6Bytes = array [0..15] of Byte;
```

I need to manipulate the IPv6 addresses in a number of ways including adding, dividing, multiplying etc. Can anyone suggest a good way to do this?

I guess I should have mentioned that I'm working with Delphi 2009

Comment: Why wouldn't you store them internally as a 2D array? 8x2 bytes, just like an IPv4 address would be manipulated as 4x1 bytes.

Comment: I'm using the same type that is used in Synapse so I can use several of the functions it already provides. Not sure why they don't store it as 8x2, but that's the way it is :)

Comment: My [IP library](https://github.com/rmaupin/IPvX/blob/main/IP.pas) for proper IP math using string inputs and outputs with some class functions has been updated. It uses a lot of validations, and it even uses compressed, mixed, and compressed-mixed IPv6 addresses. The library is used in the [IPvX](https://github.com/rmaupin/IPvX) calculator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying many of the suggestions I could not find a library that fulfilled all my needs and were bug free. I searched a little harder and found a relatively new library by Alex Ciobanu which does BigIntegers (and Big Cardinals) seamlessly allowing you to manipulate them in much the same way as you manipulate normal Integers, Cardinals etc.

As well as BigIntegers, the library also provides a number of very useful features. From the readme:

- A set of generic collections classes
  (List, Dictionary, HashSet, etc).
- Date/Time functionality all combined
  in a few structures (somehow
  equivalent to .NET's DateTime
  structure)
- Type Support concept that defines a
  set of default "support classes" for
  each built-in Delphi types (used as
  defaults in collections). Custom
  "type support" classes can be
  registered for your custom data
  types.
- **BigCardinal and BigInteger data types.**
- Smart pointers in Delphi

The library is being actively developed. In fact, the author fixed a small bug I found within a day.

You can read more about the library on [Alex's](http://alex.ciobanu.org/?page_id=162) blog and download DeHL from [Google code](http://code.google.com/p/delphilhlplib/).

Answer (score 4):

Jes Klinke wrote a bignum unit for Pascal [here](http://users.cybercity.dk/~dko5442/bignum.pas).

Disclaimer : I have not used this library personally.

Comment: Wow... handles Int128, Int256 ...all the way up to Int3k plus a few just in case.  :)  Nice find, it looks like it would solve the problem well, although I have not dug too deep into the pieces yet. (+1 wish I could give more)

Comment: I tried using this library, but it has a major bug in the subtraction function. I tried to contact the author, but have not received a reply. See my own answer to this question for another option.

Answer (score 3):

I once wrote a [IPv4 and IPv6 conversion unit](https://github.com/NLDelphi/NLDUtils/blob/main/IPTypes.pas) including a custom variant type for both types of IP addresses.

For instance, with these Variant types, the following example arithmetics and conversions are possible:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I4: TIPv4;
  I6: TIPv6;
  V1, V2, V3, V4: Variant;
begin
  I4 := StrToIPv4('192.0.2.128');
  I6 := IPv4ToIPv6(I4);
  V1 := VarIPv6Create('2001:db8:85a3:0:0:8a2e:0370:7334');
  V2 := IPv6ToVar(I6);
  V3 := V1 - V2;
  V4 := V1 or V2;
  if V3 < V4 then
    Log(V3 + ' is smaller than ' + V4);
  if V2.Equals('::ffff:192.0.2.128') or V2.IsZero then
    Log('OK');
  Log('V1 = ' + V1.AsStringOutwritten);
  Log('V2 = ' + V2.AsURL);
  Log('V3 = ' + V3.AsStringCompressed);
  V4.Follow;
end;

procedure TForm1.Log(const S: String);
begin
  Memo.Lines.Add(S);
end;
```

Custom variant types really are quite powerfull.

Comment: I've downloaded your IPv4 and IPv6 conversion unit and first of all I have to congratulate you for your work, it's excellent. Now what's really missing in your unit is a function to verify if a certain IPv6 address is IN ot OUT the scope of an IPv6 subnet. Something like IsInIPv6Subnet('2001:db8:4000:0123:ac45::01ff','2001:db8:4000::/36');
Any plans to add such function(s)?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if you can add, you can then use it to subtract, multiply and divide using addition.  Should I assume overflows will be simply ignored?

I seem to recall a method of adding bit-oriented variables using XOR.  I am looking for that answer now.

Hopefully, this will point you in the right direction.  If I can find that XOR code, I will post it for you.

Here it is:
Bitwise operation
Exclusive disjunction is often used for bitwise operations. Examples: 
1 xor 1 = 0
1 xor 0 = 1
1110 xor 1001 = 0111 (this is equivalent to addition without carry)

And the reference is:
http://www.absoluteastronomy.com/topics/Exclusive_disjunction