# IP Address String Routines in Delphi?

Tags: string, delphi, delphi-7, ip-address

I'm looking for a way in Delphi to validate and manipulate IP Addresses. Some of the things it should be able to do is...

- Verify that a string is a valid IP address
- Verify that a string is a valid subnet mask
- Verify that an IP address is within a given Subnet
- Some type (record or string or whatever) which is meant for storing an IP address
- Basic conversion of an IP address types, such as `String` or `Array[0..3] of Byte`
- Any other IP address routines that can make IP manipulation easier

The basic reason is that I want to see if these things are already out there before I go ahead and reinvent them.

Comment: Lots and lots of questions. What libraries are you planning to use? Winsock? Indy? Whatever library you use will most likely have all this covered.

Comment: I don't plan on using any libraries like that. I plan to just manipulate IP strings. But if anything, just raw winsock.

Comment: If you don't want to reinvent these things then you are looking for a library, in my opinion.

Comment: Just pick a library.  Synapse, ICS, Indy. Etc.

Comment: Indy has some class methods and global functions for this kind of thing. So, even if you're not using their components to connect, take a look at the library, especially the IdGlobal unit.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I didn't say I don't want to reinvent them, that would be a good experience. I'd rather have some good reference to how to do so before I try to make my own. WinSock looks like it has some tools, but it also has many things I don't need, and it also requires some lower-level coding. I'll try the Synapse.

Comment: Libraries are like that. You just use the parts that you need. You won't use all of Synapse either. Delphi comes with Indy by the way.

Comment: See also: [Arithmetic with IPv6 addresses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697731/arithmetic-with-ipv6-addresses-large-integers).

Comment: To tell you the truth, I've personally never worked with IPv6 and in fact always disable it from all our computers (because our DHCP is flaky with IPv6). However, that poses the point that I should implement v6 too because hey, I gotta learn sometime :D

Comment: My [IP library](https://github.com/rmaupin/IPvX/blob/main/IP.pas) for proper IP math using string inputs and outputs with some class functions has been updated. It uses a lot of validations, and it even uses compressed, mixed, and compressed-mixed IPv6 addresses. The library is used in the [IPvX](https://github.com/rmaupin/IPvX) calculator.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I also once wrote a [IPv4 and IPv6 conversion unit](https://github.com/NLDelphi/NLDUtils/blob/main/NLDIPTypes.pas) including a custom variant type for both types of IP addresses. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6840912/757830) shows a few examples of its capabilities. Originally, it was designed to visualize values of various types in scale on some slider control <sup>1)</sup>. The requirements then were such that default existing libraries weren't sufficient, but I agree with the comments here that you probably will be helped with just Indy (10!) or alike.

Answering your list of questions with a few code snippets from that unit:

- Q4: Storage type for IP types:

  ```
    const
      IPv4BitSize = SizeOf(Byte) * 4 * 8;
      IPv6BitSize = SizeOf(Word) * 8 * 8;

    type
      T4 = 0..3;
      T8 = 0..7;
      TIPv4ByteArray = array[T4] of Byte;
      TIPv6WordArray = array[T8] of Word;

      TIPv4 = packed record
        case Integer of
          0: (D, C, B, A: Byte);
          1: (Groups: TIPv4ByteArray);
          2: (Value: Cardinal);
      end;

      TIPv6 = packed record
        case Integer of
          0: (H, G, F, E, D, C, B, A: Word);
          1: (Groups: TIPv6WordArray);
      end;
  ```
- Q5: Conversion of IP address strings to these record or array types:

  ```
    function StrToIPv4(const S: String): TIPv4;
    var
      SIP: String;
      Start: Integer;
      I: T4;
      Index: Integer;
      Count: Integer;
      SGroup: String;
      G: Integer;
    begin
      SIP := S + '.';
      Start := 1;
      for I := High(T4) downto Low(T4) do
      begin
        Index := PosEx('.', SIP, Start);
        if Index = 0 then
          IPv4ErrorFmt(SInvalidIPv4Value, S);
        Count := Index - Start + 1;
        SGroup := Copy(SIP, Start, Count - 1);
        if TryStrToInt(SGroup, G) and (G >= Low(Word)) and (G <= High(Word)) then
            Result.Groups[I] := G
          else
            Result.Groups[I] := 0;
        Inc(Start, Count);
      end;
    end;

    function StrToIPv6(const S: String): TIPv6;
    { Valid examples for S:
      2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334
      2001:db8:85a3:0:0:8a2e:370:7334
      2001:db8:85a3::8a2e:370:7334
      ::8a2e:370:7334
      2001:db8:85a3::
      ::1
      ::
      ::ffff:c000:280
      ::ffff:192.0.2.128 }
    var
      ZeroPos: Integer;
      DotPos: Integer;
      SIP: String;
      Start: Integer;
      Index: Integer;
      Count: Integer;
      SGroup: String;
      G: Integer;

      procedure NormalNotation;
      var
        I: T8;
      begin
        SIP := S + ':';
        Start := 1;
        for I := High(T8) downto Low(T8) do
        begin
          Index := PosEx(':', SIP, Start);
          if Index = 0 then
            IPv6ErrorFmt(SInvalidIPv6Value, S);
          Count := Index - Start + 1;
          SGroup := '$' + Copy(SIP, Start, Count - 1);
          if not TryStrToInt(SGroup, G) or (G > High(Word)) or (G < 0) then
            IPv6ErrorFmt(SInvalidIPv6Value, S);
          Result.Groups[I] := G;
          Inc(Start, Count);
        end;
      end;

      procedure CompressedNotation;
      var
        I: T8;
        A: array of Word;
      begin
        SIP := S + ':';
        Start := 1;
        I := High(T8);
        while Start < ZeroPos do
        begin
          Index := PosEx(':', SIP, Start);
          if Index = 0 then
            IPv6ErrorFmt(SInvalidIPv6Value, S);
          Count := Index - Start + 1;
          SGroup := '$' + Copy(SIP, Start, Count - 1);
          if not TryStrToInt(SGroup, G) or (G > High(Word)) or (G < 0) then
            IPv6ErrorFmt(SInvalidIPv6Value, S);
          Result.Groups[I] := G;
          Inc(Start, Count);
          Dec(I);
        end;
        FillChar(Result.H, (I + 1) * SizeOf(Word), 0);
        if ZeroPos < (Length(S) - 1) then
        begin
          SetLength(A, I + 1);
          Start := ZeroPos + 2;
          repeat
            Index := PosEx(':', SIP, Start);
            if Index > 0 then
            begin
              Count := Index - Start + 1;
              SGroup := '$' + Copy(SIP, Start, Count - 1);
              if not TryStrToInt(SGroup, G) or (G > High(Word)) or (G < 0) then
                IPv6ErrorFmt(SInvalidIPv6Value, S);
              A[I] := G;
              Inc(Start, Count);
              Dec(I);
            end;
          until Index = 0;
          Inc(I);
          Count := Length(A) - I;
          Move(A[I], Result.H, Count * SizeOf(Word));
        end;
      end;

      procedure DottedQuadNotation;
      var
        I: T4;
      begin
        if UpperCase(Copy(S, ZeroPos + 2, 4)) <> 'FFFF' then
          IPv6ErrorFmt(SInvalidIPv6Value, S);
        FillChar(Result.E, 5 * SizeOf(Word), 0);
        Result.F := $FFFF;
        SIP := S + '.';
        Start := ZeroPos + 7;
        for I := Low(T4) to High(T4) do
        begin
          Index := PosEx('.', SIP, Start);
          if Index = 0 then
            IPv6ErrorFmt(SInvalidIPv6Value, S);
          Count := Index - Start + 1;
          SGroup := Copy(SIP, Start, Count - 1);
          if not TryStrToInt(SGroup, G) or (G > High(Byte)) or (G < 0) then
            IPv6ErrorFmt(SInvalidIPv6Value, S);
          case I of
            0: Result.G := G shl 8;
            1: Inc(Result.G, G);
            2: Result.H := G shl 8;
            3: Inc(Result.H, G);
          end;
          Inc(Start, Count);
        end;
      end;

    begin
      ZeroPos := Pos('::', S);
      if ZeroPos = 0 then
        NormalNotation
      else
      begin
        DotPos := Pos('.', S);
        if DotPos = 0 then
          CompressedNotation
        else
          DottedQuadNotation;
      end;
    end;
  ```

For Q1 to Q3 you have to derive some routines yourself, but that *should* not be any problem.

<sup>1) For those interested, it's [this slider control](https://github.com/NGLN/AwSlider) and [this topic](http://www.nldelphi.com/forum/showthread.php?t=36251) served as initiation of this unit.</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I've also noticed that you like to implement embedding methods inside of methods, same as the glass drawing you put together for my other question... I use it sometimes too but otherwise I usually declare other methods directly in the unit or a class.

Comment: @Jerry These are no methods because they are no member of a class.

Comment: @Jerry I embed routines within routines when it is a gain in readability, wherelse it would result in one large function or procedure. When I would need comments in code to explain myself what I am doing, e.g. where something ends and starts, then I split. If those embedded routines prove to be useful elsewhere, then they evolve to isolated code or even a separate unit.

Comment: @NGLN, Thank you, but there are 2 missing functions:  IPv4ErrorFmt, IPv6ErrorFmt, maybe to raise an exception, It's right?

Comment: @antonio They're added (already long time ago ;-)).

Answer (score 4):

I have already written all the functions you require but I'm afraid I'm not in a position to share the code.

However, the [Synapse](http://www.ararat.cz/synapse/doku.php/start) library contains quite a few functions in the **synaip** unit. e.g.

```
function IsIP(const Value: string): Boolean;
function IsIP6(const Value: string): Boolean;
function IPToID(Host: string): Ansistring;
function StrToIp6(value: string): TIp6Bytes;
function Ip6ToStr(value: TIp6Bytes): string;
function StrToIp(value: string): integer;
function IpToStr(value: integer): string;
function ReverseIP(Value: AnsiString): AnsiString;
function ReverseIP6(Value: AnsiString): AnsiString;
```

When I tried the functions a few years ago, the IPv6 functions were a bit buggy, especially when dealing with compressed IPv6 addresses.

If you want to roll your own, here a few pointers:

- Manipulating IPv4 addresses is fairly simple as they only consist of
  32 bits which can be stored in a standard integer type. IPv6
  addresses are harder as they need 128 bits and no native type has
  that many bits.
- Before trying to manipulate an IP address, first convert it into an
  integer (IPv4 only of course, IPv6 will require a different storage
  method). To do this, split the IP address using '.' as a delimiter.
  Check each individual value only contains numbers and falls between 0
  and 255 then use these values to generate the final integer.
- Once the IP address has been converted into an integer, you can
  manipulate it however you like. For example, given an IP address and
  a subnet mask you can find the subnet that the IP address belongs to
  e.g. IPtoInt(IPAddress) AND NOT(IPToInt(SubnetMask)) = The integer of
  the subnet. Now, you can comaare an integer IP address to the integer
  subnet to see if the IP falls within the subnet.
- Finally, convert the integer IP address back into a string.

If you have any specific questions I can try to answer them too.

Comment: Most of those same functions are also in IdGlobal.

Comment: Note: Indy 9 limits that list to only IsValidIP and IsHostname.

Comment: IPv4ToUInt32() in IdGlobal seems buggy, it accepts "300.1.1.1" as a valid ip.